# SweetAlert is displaying UTF-8 characters wrong

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8, sweetalert

I am using sweetalert2 in a project, I am displaying Arabic text on the pop up. However, the text shown is not being encoded correctly. I have already added the meta tag to the head of the website, the whole page is showing the text correctly, except for the text on the pop up.

[image]

Comment: The META tag is possibly the most irrelevant bit. You need to actually use UTF-8 everywhere, not just declare you're doing it.

Comment: Can you please clarify more about what you mean?

Comment: See [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) for a list of checks.